# Mac $PATH executables not available in Terminal

Tags: macos, path

I'm new to Mac and am trying to add things to my $PATH so I can call things like "mysql" and "mongod" anywhere on the terminal.  Here's my current .bash_profile.  What am I doing wrong?  Running OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

```
# Additional binary folders
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/iqm377/bin

# MongoDB
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/iqm377/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.5/bin

# MySQL
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/iqm377/XAMPP/bin
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you're doing anything wrong. Why do you think this isn't working? What are you doing in a terminal that should work but isn't? If you do `echo $PATH` at the prompt, does it have those directories?

Comment: When I type mysql in terminal , I get a message that says "command not found."  Here's the result of echoing the path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/iqm377/bin:/Users/iqm377/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.5/bin:/Users/iqm377/XAMPP/bin

Comment: you sourced the file or restarted ?

Comment: Yea, I right click/quit the terminal and restarted it.  Looks like "mongod" is working now, but mysql still gives a command not found error

Comment: I even navigate to the XAMPP/bin directory and running "mysql" from there doesn't work.  When I ls, it's definitely in there though.

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes in you $PATH variable just like this

```
export PATH="~/mongodb/bin:$PATH"
```